# Estimating high resolution images from lower ones using a Keras model based on ConvLSTM2D

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, keras

I'm trying to use the following `ConvLSTM2D` architecture to estimate high resolution image sequences from low resolution ones:

```python
import numpy as np, scipy.ndimage, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, ConvLSTM2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix, cohen_kappa_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler
np.random.seed(123)

raw = np.arange(96).reshape(8,3,4)
data1 = scipy.ndimage.zoom(raw, zoom=(1,100,100), order=1, mode='nearest') #low res
print (data1.shape)
#(8, 300, 400)

data2 = scipy.ndimage.zoom(raw, zoom=(1,100,100), order=3, mode='nearest') #high res
print (data2.shape)
#(8, 300, 400)

X_train = data1.reshape(data1.shape[0], 1, data1.shape[1], data1.shape[2], 1)
Y_train = data2.reshape(data2.shape[0], 1, data2.shape[1], data2.shape[2], 1)
#(samples,time, rows, cols, channels)

model = Sequential()
input_shape = (data1.shape[0], data1.shape[1], data1.shape[2], 1)
#samples, time, rows, cols, channels
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(16, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='sigmoid',padding='same',input_shape=input_shape))     
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(8, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='sigmoid',padding='same'))

print (model.summary())

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, 
          batch_size=1, epochs=10, verbose=1)

x,y = model.evaluate(X_train, Y_train, verbose=0)
print (x,y)
```

This declaration will result in the following `Value` error:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv_lst_m2d_2: expected ndim=5, found ndim=4

How can I correct this `ValueError`? I think problem is with input shapes, but could not figure out what exactly is wrong.
Notice that the output should be sequences of images too, instead of a classification result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because `LSTMs` require temporal data, but your first one was declared as a `many-to-one` model, which outputs a tensor of shape `(batch_size, 300, 400, 16)`. That is, batches of images:

```py
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(16, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='sigmoid',padding='same',input_shape=input_shape))     
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(8, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='sigmoid',padding='same'))
```

You want the output to be a tensor of shape `(batch_size, 8, 300, 400, 16)` (i.e. sequences of images), so they can be consumed by the second LSTM. The way to fix this is to add `return_sequences` in the first LSTM definition:

```py
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(16, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='sigmoid',padding='same',input_shape=input_shape,
                     return_sequences=True))
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(8, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='sigmoid',padding='same'))
```

You mentioned classification. If what you indent is to classify entire sequences, then you need a classifier at the end:

```py
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(16, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='sigmoid',padding='same',input_shape=input_shape,
                     return_sequences=True))
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(8, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='sigmoid',padding='same'))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))  # output shape: (None, 10)
```

But if you are trying to classify each image **within** the sequences, then you can simply reapply the classifier using `TimeDistributed`:

```py
x = Input(shape=(300, 400, 8))
y = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
y = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(y)
classifier = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)

x = Input(shape=(data1.shape[0], data1.shape[1], data1.shape[2], 1))
y = ConvLSTM2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3),
               activation='sigmoid',
               padding='same',
               return_sequences=True)(x)
y = ConvLSTM2D(8, kernel_size=(3, 3),
               activation='sigmoid',
               padding='same',
               return_sequences=True)(y)
y = TimeDistributed(classifier)(y)  # output shape: (None, 8, 10)

model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
```

Finally, take a look at the examples in keras repository. There's one for a [generative model using ConvLSTM2D](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/conv_lstm.py).

---

Edit: to estimate data2 from data1...

If I got it right this time, `X_train` should be 1 sample of a stack of 8 (300, 400, 1) images, not 8 samples of a stack of 1 image of shape (300, 400, 1).
If that's true, then:

```py
X_train = data1.reshape(data1.shape[0], 1, data1.shape[1], data1.shape[2], 1)
Y_train = data2.reshape(data2.shape[0], 1, data2.shape[1], data2.shape[2], 1)
```

Should be updated to:

```py
X_train = data1.reshape(1, data1.shape[0], data1.shape[1], data1.shape[2], 1)
Y_train = data2.reshape(1, data2.shape[0], data2.shape[1], data2.shape[2], 1)
```

Also, `accuracy` doesn't usually make sense when your loss is mse. You can use other metrics such as `mae`.

Now you just need to update your model to return sequences and to have a single unit in the last layer (because the images you are trying to estimate have a single channel):

```py
model = Sequential()
input_shape = (data1.shape[0], data1.shape[1], data1.shape[2], 1)
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same',
                     input_shape=input_shape,
                     return_sequences=True))
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(1, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same',
                     return_sequences=True))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
```

After that, `model.fit(X_train, Y_train, ...)` will start training normally:

```py
Using TensorFlow backend.
(8, 300, 400)
(8, 300, 400)
Epoch 1/10

1/1 [==============================] - 5s 5s/step - loss: 2993.8701
Epoch 2/10

1/1 [==============================] - 5s 5s/step - loss: 2992.4492
Epoch 3/10

1/1 [==============================] - 5s 5s/step - loss: 2991.4536
Epoch 4/10

1/1 [==============================] - 5s 5s/step - loss: 2989.8523
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand your comment. `time` is the temporal dim and `1` is the number of input channels, yes. After going through the two `ConvLSTM2D` you declared, the output shape will be `(batch_size, time, 300, 400, 8)`, because it's returning sequences and there's 8 units in the last `LSTM`. The classifier accepts inputs of shape `(batch_size, 300, 400, 8)`, which are batches of images. Wrapped around `TimeDistributed`, it will be able to process the sequences coming out of the second `ConvLSTM2D`.

Comment: Okay, so there's two stacks and you want to fuse them. How would you like to do this? Are you planning to compare them or concatenate them?

Comment: Oh, I see. I have updated the answer to match your image estimation task.

Comment: That's a little different from your original question, where `y_train` had the same shape as `x_train`. I would suggest removing `return_sequences=True` from the last layer (which creates a model that outputs images of shape `(300, 400, 1)`). Observe that `y_train` would need to be reshaped from `(samples, 1, 300, 400, 1)` to `(samples, 300, 400, 1)`. If that doesn't bring good results, then maybe keep `return_sequences=True` and add a few `Conv3d` layers at the end, which would produce images by convolving the `(8, 300, 400)` feature space outputted by the LSTM.