# Keras ConvLSTM2D: ValueError on output layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am trying to train a 2D convolutional LSTM to make categorical predictions based on video data. However, my output layer seems to be running into a problem:

"ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1939, 9)"

My current model is based off of the [ConvLSTM2D example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/conv_lstm.py) provided by Keras Team. I believe that the above error is the result of my misunderstanding the example and its basic principles.

**Data**

I have an arbitrary number of videos, where each video contains an arbitrary number of frames. Each frame is 135x240x1 (color channels last). This results in an input shape of (None, None, 135, 240, 1), where the two "None" values are batch size and timesteps in that order. If I train on a single video with a 1052 frames, then my input shape becomes (1, 1052, 135, 240, 1).

For each frame, the model should predict values between 0 and 1 across 9 classes. This means that my output shape is (None, None, 9). If I train on a single video with 1052 frames, then this shape becomes (1, 1052, 9).

**Model**

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv_lst_m2d_1 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, None, 135, 240, 40 59200
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, None, 135, 240, 40 160
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_2 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, None, 135, 240, 40 115360
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, None, 135, 240, 40 160
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_3 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, None, 135, 240, 40 115360
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, None, 135, 240, 40 160
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, None, 135, 240, 9) 369
=================================================================
Total params: 290,769
Trainable params: 290,529
Non-trainable params: 240
```

**Source code**

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(
        filters=40,
        kernel_size=(3, 3),
        input_shape=(None, 135, 240, 1),
        padding='same',
        return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(
        filters=40,
        kernel_size=(3, 3),
        padding='same',
        return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(
        filters=40,
        kernel_size=(3, 3),
        padding='same',
        return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(
        units=classes,
        activation='softmax'
))
model.compile(
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer='adadelta'
)
model.fit_generator(generator=training_sequence)
```

**Traceback**

```
Epoch 1/1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\lstm.py", line 128, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\lstm.py", line 108, in main
    model.fit_generator(generator=training_sequence)
  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\capstone-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\capstone-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 1253, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\capstone-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\capstone-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2244, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\capstone-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1884, in train_on_batch
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\capstone-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1487, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\capstone-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 113, in _standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1939, 9)
```

A sample input shape printed with batch size set to 1 is (1, 1389, 135, 240, 1). This shape matches the requirements I described above, so I think my Keras Sequence subclass (in the source code as "training_sequence") is correct.

I suspect that the problem is caused by my going directly from BatchNormalization() to Dense(). After all, the traceback indicates that the problem is occurring in dense_1 (the final layer). However, I wouldn't want to lead anyone astray with my beginner-level knowledge, so please take my assessment with a grain of salt.

**Edit 3/27/2018**

After reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49468183/4674553), which involves a similar model, I changed my final ConvLSTM2D layer so that the return_sequences parameter is set to False instead of True. I also added a GlobalAveragePooling2D layer before my Dense layer. The updated model is as follows:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv_lst_m2d_1 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, None, 135, 240, 40 59200
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, None, 135, 240, 40 160
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_2 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, None, 135, 240, 40 115360
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, None, 135, 240, 40 160
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_3 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, 135, 240, 40)      115360
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 135, 240, 40)      160
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d_1 ( (None, 40)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 9)                 369
=================================================================
Total params: 290,769
Trainable params: 290,529
Non-trainable params: 240
```

Here is a new copy of the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\lstm.py", line 131, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\lstm.py", line 111, in main
    model.fit_generator(generator=training_sequence)
  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\capstone-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\capstone-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 1253, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\capstone-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\capstone-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2244, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\capstone-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1884, in train_on_batch
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\capstone-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1487, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\capstone-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 113, in _standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1034, 9)
```

I printed the x and y shapes on this run. x was (1, 1034, 135, 240, 1) and y was (1, 1034, 9). This may narrow the problem down. It looks like the problem is related to the y data rather than the x data. Specifically, the Dense layer doesn't like the temporal dim. However, I am not sure how to rectify this issue.

**Edit 3/28/2018**

Yu-Yang's solution worked. For anyone with a similar problem who wants to see what the final model looked like, here is the summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv_lst_m2d_1 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, None, 135, 240, 40 59200
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, None, 135, 240, 40 160
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_2 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, None, 135, 240, 40 115360
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, None, 135, 240, 40 160
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_3 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, None, 135, 240, 40 115360
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, None, 135, 240, 40 160
_________________________________________________________________
average_pooling3d_1 (Average (None, None, 1, 1, 40)    0
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, None, 40)          0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, None, 9)           369
=================================================================
Total params: 290,769
Trainable params: 290,529
Non-trainable params: 240
```

Also, the source code:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(
        filters=40,
        kernel_size=(3, 3),
        input_shape=(None, 135, 240, 1),
        padding='same',
        return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(
        filters=40,
        kernel_size=(3, 3),
        padding='same',
        return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(
        filters=40,
        kernel_size=(3, 3),
        padding='same',
        return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(AveragePooling3D((1, 135, 240)))
model.add(Reshape((-1, 40)))
model.add(Dense(
        units=9,
        activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer='adadelta'
)
```

Comment: Any luck on Keras github? Curious about this as well.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Are you asking me if I've opened a new issue there?

Comment: @MatthewHarrison Just a clarification, if you are expecting 9 values between 0 and 1, why is your activation softmax? This is not classification right?

Comment: A frame/label pair is supposed to be able to yield multiple classes. An example output would be something like: [ 0.2, 0.7, 0.3, 0.2, 0.9, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2 ]

Comment: @MatthewHarrison So you will be passing in 9 features for each frame and you want 9 predictions at the end for each video. right?

Comment: I am passing in 9 features per frame and want 9 predictions per frame. The goal is to have it watch a frame buffer in real time and make predictions during each frame.

Comment: It's possible that I am misunderstanding the terminology, so I'll try to explain in terms that I am more comfortable with. For each frame of a video, I am passing in a 135x240 buffer (x) along with 9 labels (y). The state of the labels on one frame is likely to influence the state of the labels on a later frame. Thus, for any given frame, I want to be able to predict the labels for that frame, and I want my prediction to account for the states of labels on previous frames.

Comment: I understand your problem now, that you want to 9 outputs for each frame which are probabilities of the frame being in that class. A ConvLSTM will take all the frames and aggregate them through time and see how they change through time. I do not think thats what you want to do. What determines whether a frame is in a class or not?

Comment: If you want a prediction per frame, then you should definitely set `return_sequences=True` in your last `ConvLSTM2D` layer.

Comment: You can replace the `GlobalAveragePooling2D()` layer with `AveragePooling3D((1, 135, 240))` plus `Reshape((-1, 40))` to make the output shape compatible with your target array.

Comment: @user239457 The frames are captured graphical buffer from a game, and the labels are which buttons were pressed at the time of the capture.

Comment: @Yu-Yang Thank you for the suggestions. Your changes allow the model to compile and start running, though not in TensorFlow-GPU. I will look into my current setup and see if there's an issue there.

Comment: @Yu-Yang For some reason, adding the AveragePooling3D layer causes the TensorFlow backend to throw a TypeError with the message "avg_pool3d() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data_format'". I am passing the same arguments that you specified. Could this be a defect in Keras, or is it more likely a simple mistake on my part?

Comment: Sounds like a mismatch in Keras and TF versions. Which version of TF do you use? I've tested on 1.6 and 1.7 and they both work fine. Maybe you can try to upgrade TF or downgrade Keras?

Comment: @Yu-Yang I'm running Keras-GPU version 2.1.5 and TensorFlow-GPU 1.1.0. Could you clarify which module is which version in your environment?

Comment: 1.1.0 is probably too old for Keras 2.1.5. Even TF 1.4 is known to have [some problem](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9621) with the latest Keras. If it's hard for you to upgrade TF, maybe you can downgrade Keras to 2.0.8 or even older versions.

Comment: I have `tensorflow==1.7.0rc1` (compiled from source, so the package name does not contain "gpu") and Keras at the latest master branch (pip install from GitHub).

Comment: The problem was that I had installed tensorflow-gpu and keras via conda, when I should have used pip instead. The model compiles and runs now! I run out of VRAM, but the problem I opened this thread for is now resolved.

Comment: @Yu-Yang please consider rewriting your suggestions as an answer so that I can give you credit for your efforts, and so that anyone who finds this thread can see the resolution.

Comment: Sure. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a prediction per frame, then you should definitely set `return_sequences=True` in your last `ConvLSTM2D` layer.

For the `ValueError` on target shape, replace the `GlobalAveragePooling2D()` layer with `AveragePooling3D((1, 135, 240))` plus `Reshape((-1, 40))` to make the output shape compatible with your target array.

Comment: Thanks! I went ahead and edited my question to show the result of implementing your changes.