# Keras ConvLSTM2D: why use the averagepooling3d and how to to regression

Tags: python, keras, regression, lstm

i have been studying [Keras ConvLSTM2D: ValueError on output layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49524396/keras-convlstm2d-valueerror-on-output-layer)

i want to use the same code but i want to do regression ( single value ).
I dont know how to do this. And i also dont understand the use of last layers of this post code. Why is averagepolling3d  used?

the code from link is

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(
        filters=40,
        kernel_size=(3, 3),
        input_shape=(None, 135, 240, 1),
        padding='same',
        return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(
        filters=40,
        kernel_size=(3, 3),
        padding='same',
        return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(
        filters=40,
        kernel_size=(3, 3),
        padding='same',
        return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(AveragePooling3D((1, 135, 240)))
model.add(Reshape((-1, 40)))
model.add(Dense(
        units=9,
        activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer='adadelta'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`AveragePooling3D` is used to reduce each frame in a sequence to a single value + to reduce the #parameters in the Dense Layer. So, the dimension becomes `(None, 40 , 1 , 1 ,1 )`. Then, using `Reshape` allows it to use for fully-connected part.

Also, as in [Keras ConvLSTM2D: ValueError on output layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49524396/keras-convlstm2d-valueerror-on-output-layer), `AveragePooling3D` is used instead of `GlobalMaxPooling2D` since data is 5D and `Global` operations leaves only `(batch_size, channels)` which is not desirable in your case.